# How to change color my button color

Tags: android

My working a woman pregnant app.
I'm trying to baby kick the counter.
Once the button is clicked, counter increase.
But I want every click, button change color like web hover.
I try onclick but one time change colo and later not changed

This sample onlick code

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if( v == counterbutton) {
            counterbutton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_background));
            get_last_counter++;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = MotherActivity.preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt(MotherActivity.COUNTER_INCREASE, get_last_counter);
            editor.apply();
            counter.setText(counter_writer(get_last_counter));
        }
    }
```

Button xml code

```
<Button
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/kick"
                    android:id="@+id/counterbutton"
                    android:background="@color/app_pink"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue_text_color"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Sorry bad english.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest looking into selectors, [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/) is a nice example I found.

Comment: Yes is true answer thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

On every click you set the same color. you should have a variable and alternate like :

```
mClickIndex = 0 
if(mClickIndex % 2 == 0){
counterbutton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_background));
} else {
counterbutton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(OTHER COLOR));
}
mClickIndex++;
```

Comment: I want one click change to color. Like web hover.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        switch(id) { 
        case R.id.counterbuton:        
                counterbutton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_background));
                get_last_counter++;
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = MotherActivity.preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt(MotherActivity.COUNTER_INCREASE, get_last_counter);
                editor.apply();
                counter.setText(counter_writer(get_last_counter)); 
        break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will works.

```
Random rnd = new Random(); 
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));   
counterbutton.setBackgroundColor(color);
```